# UIToolbar hairline

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationbar, uitoolbar

I would like to replicate the AppStore screen where they have a UIToolbar under the navigation bar. The hairline is removed from the navigation bar but they have it for the toolbar.

This is how it looks like:
[image]

In order to do this i have set the UIToolbar to have a Black style + custom backgroundColor:

```
[[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor navBarBackgroundColor]];
```

To remove the hairline from the navigation bar I did:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]
                                                forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

And i got this:

[image]

I was thinking that in order to add a hairline to the bottom i could create an UIImage with a 1px line on the bottom but I would like to do it in some other nicer way if possible.

Comment: is `clipToBounds` `TRUE`?

Comment: Haven't changed the clipToBounds property. It's set to NO for the toolbar.

Comment: Apple provides sample code on how to do this. You can find it here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/NavBar/Listings/ExtendedNavBar_ExtendedNavBarView_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007418-ExtendedNavBar_ExtendedNavBarView_m-DontLinkElementID_26

Answer (score 0):

You can add a bottom border by adding a sublayer to your toolbar's layer:

```
CALayer *bottomBorder = [CALayer layer];

bottomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, toolbar.frame.size.height - 1.0f, toolbar.frame.size.width, 1.0f);

bottomBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.8f 
                                             alpha:1.0f].CGColor;

[toolbar.layer addSublayer:bottomBorder];
```

Comment: In iOS7 at least this doesn't produce what is required.